# How to return object details and Aggregated data under the same Django Rest API

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to return Object details and Aggregated data under the same Django rest api. Can it be possible from ModelViewSet? If not what is the correct way of doing this?

Here is my Code.

```
#Tin 
class TinTable(CoreModel):
    tin=models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    assessee_name=models.CharField(max_length=500)

def __str__(self):
    return self.tin

# Financial Year
class FinancialYear(CoreModel):
    financial_year = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["start_year"]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.financial_year
```

Ledger Class

```
# Ledger 
class Ledger(CoreModel):
    
    UNDISPUTED = 0
    APPEAL = 1
    TRIB = 2
    HC = 3
    ONE_SEVENTY_THREE = 4
    ONE_TWEENTY_ONE = 5
    ADR = 6
    

    Ledger_SECTION_CHOICES = (
        (UNDISPUTED, 'Undisputed'),
        (APPEAL, 'Appeal'),
        (TRIB, 'Tribunal'),
        (HC, 'High Court'),
        (ONE_SEVENTY_THREE, '173'),
        (ONE_TWEENTY_ONE, '121/A'),
        (ADR, 'ADR')

    )
    tin=models.ForeignKey(TinTable, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    financial_year = models.ForeignKey(FinancialYear, on_delete = models.CASCADE)


    demand = models.FloatField(default = 0.0 ) #demand
    disputed_demand = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    payment = models.FloatField(default = 0.0 ) #payment
    balance = models.FloatField(default = 0.0 )
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=Ledger_SECTION_CHOICES, default=UNDISPUTED)

    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tin.tin
```

Serializer of Ledger

```
class LedgerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    financial_year = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=FinancialYear.objects.all(), source='financial_year', write_only=True
    )
    tin = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=TinTable.objects.all(), source='tin', write_only=True
    )
    assessee_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='tin.assessee_name'
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Ledger
        fields = ('tin','assessee_name','financial_year','demand','disputed_demand', 'payment','status')
```

View of Ledger

```
class LedgerView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LedgerSerializer
    queryset = Ledger.objects.active()
```

The output I want

```
{
    "results":[
        {
            "tin":"222222222222",
            "name":"Karim",
            "total_disputed": 5000,
            "total_undisputed": 900,
            "total_payment": 500,

            "financial_details":[
                {
                    "year": "2017-2018",
                    "undisputed":900,
                    "disputed":0,
                    "payment":500,
                    "status":"undisputed"
                },
                {
                    "year": "2018-2019",
                    "undisputed":0,
                    "disputed":5000,
                    "payment":0,
                    "status":"disputed"
                }

            ]
            

        },
        {
            "tin":"3333333333333",
            "name":"Rahim",
            "total_disputed": 8000,
            "total_undisputed": 1900,
            "total_payment": 1500,

            "financial_details":[
                {
                    "year": "2017-2018",
                    "undisputed":900,
                    "disputed":3000,
                    "payment":500,
                    "status":"undisputed"
                },
                {
                    "year": "2018-2019",
                    "undisputed":1000,
                    "disputed":5000,
                    "payment":1000,
                    "status":"disputed"
                },

               ........ # more data
            ]
            

        },
              ........ # more data
    ]
}
```

It would be so helpful to get a detailed answer for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you are asking about how to get this expected output with `GET` request right? because I noticed that you added `write_only=True` to `tin` and `financial_year `.

Comment: Yes, a get API will do

Comment: in this case, I will share my answer regarding `GET` request only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a serializer to serialize `financial_details`, for ex:

```
class FinancialYearSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
            model = FinancialYear
            fields = # your desired fields...

class LedgerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    financial_details = FinancialYearSerializer(source='financial_year', read_only=True, many=True)
    # the rest of your fields
    
    class Meta:
        model = Ledger
        fields = ('tin','assessee_name','financial_year','demand','disputed_demand', 'payment','status')
```

For other fields which will hold aggregated data, you can use [SerializerMethodField()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) as the docs describe.

**TIP**:

You should add `related_name` to your `ForeignKey()` fields for reverse relations, Django is already creating it with default naming but it's better to set yours.

```
tin = models.ForeignKey(TinTable, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='ledgers')
financial_year = models.ForeignKey(FinancialYear, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='ledgers')
```

Comment: I think you need to see my desired output. if you please look closely, you will see there are some aggregated fields (total_undisputed, etc.). your answer is not serving my purpose.

Comment: you didn't mention any info about these fields, add more info about them and I will update my answer, this is straight forward in general.

Comment: In my question, I have stated that I also need aggregated values in my response. Then, I have added my desired output. Adding `FinancialYearSerializer` will show the other fields of `FinancialYear` model. So, still no it is not serving what I am looking for

Comment: why downvote? add more info to your question to make it clear before saying this answer is not helpful, the answer fixes solves`FinancialYear`, but others are not clear. make your question clear regarding other fields and I will update the answer

Comment: but don't downvote while your question is lacking what you are asking for

Comment: I have updated my answer regarding aggregated data, this is the best I can suggest without additional info or context

Comment: @pdfarhad  mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem after the update. If it doesn't then update your question with more info. and remove your downvote.